# VeeValidate 4's `max` rule is giving the message "{field} cannot be greater than 1 characters" despite using `max:256` for the rule definition

Tags: vee-validate

I have a Vue Component that uses VeeValidate 4 with `useForm` and I am seeing some weirdness with the validation message.

I'm passing in a validation schema like so:

```js
import { computed } from 'vue'
import { useForm } from 'vee-validate'

const validationSchema = computed(() => {
  title: 'required|max:256'
})

// Initialize validation
const { values, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm({
  validationSchema,
})
```

However, when I exceed the max length on the field, I get the message `"Page Title cannot be greater than 1 characters."` even though I am passing in `max:256` for the rule. (It should read `"Page Title cannot be greater than 256 characters."`)

In my global config, the message for `max` rule is:

```js
configure({
  generateMessage: localize({
    en: {
      messages: {
        max: '{field} cannot be greater than {length} characters.',
      }
    }
  })
}
```

I have tried replacing `{length}` in the above message with `{max}` and `{maxlength}` and anything else I can think of, but `{length}` is the only thing that returns an integer, and I cannot figure out why VV4 is always replacing it with `1`.

As an important sidenote, I wanted the field name to show up as "Page Title" in the validation message, so I am passing in a localization for the field name at the level of this specific component:

```js
import { configure } from 'vee-validate'
import { localize } from '@vee-validate/i18n'

configure({
  generateMessage: localize({
    en: {
      names: {
        title: 'Page Title',
      },
    },
  }),
})
```

I can't believe I'm having so much trouble over `1` in my message, instead of `256`. Any ideas on what might be wrong? Removing the localized field name doesn't affect anything.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I came across [this page about placeholder interpolation](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/guide/i18n/#placeholder-interpolation) and managed to get my code working by changing the max error message to this:

```js
configure({
  generateMessage: localize({
    en: {
      messages: {
        max: '{field} cannot be greater than 0:{length} characters.',
      }
    }
  })
}
```

(Note the `0:{length}` in the above snippet.)

Now it's working properly, although it seems odd to have to do it this way. :shrug: